# Blazor Web Assembly Client Project Imports not working

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I just created my first Blazor Web Assembly solution using .Net 8 (Had been using .Net 7).  I am finding that my Imports is not being recognized.

In App.razor, I was getting an error on context not found.  When I copied the @using statements from Imports into App.razor, the issue was resolved.

Any suggestions on how to correct this?

Comment: I have been seeing this also. Sometimes closing and reopening the tab in VS helps. Sometimes it will still build and run fine even though it is complaining about the "unknown" component.