# Error: there is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationStateProvider'

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have seen other posts on this topic, but haven't found the answer yet; I have posted the full error message below.

Also, I have just posted a question that may be related ([Blazor Web Assembly Client Project Imports not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77956382/blazor-web-assembly-client-project-imports-not-working)). This question is concerning that I just created my first Blazor web assembly solution using .NET 8 (I have correctly created .NET 7 solutions before) and am finding that the `@using` statements in my imports are not being recognized.

This error appears when I am first loading my solution in the dev environment and I get stuck on a circle that says "application loading". Not sure what else to provide.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
>
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for property 'AuthenticationStateProvider' on type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.CascadingAuthenticationState'. There is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationStateProvider'.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'AuthenticationStateProvider' on type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.CascadingAuthenticationState'. There is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationStateProvider'.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type componentType, IComponentRenderMode callerSpecifiedRenderMode, Nullable`1 parentComponentId)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame[] frames, Int32 frameIndex, Int32 parentComponentId)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()

Comment: Not only looking for answers, but any advice on where to start debugging this would be helpful.

Comment: I am not sure which template are you using and how to to set up authentication. Did you missing register something like `builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>();`?